# inline colorbox like a photo gallery

Tags: colorbox

I have a set of inline html colorbox that work and popup with text/
image/link when clicked.   I would like to know if it's possible to
make them like an image gallery where it has the prev/next arrows so a
user can just click next instead of closing and open next link?

To view a example you can view at:
http://jsfiddle.net/dwDru/

UPDATE: Figured out I needed a rel parameter and works great.